# smooth scroll navigation with active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a smooth scroll navigation bar for a website. I have managed to get the navigation bar to scroll to the different sections within the HTML document, and I been trying to get the navigation bar links to become active depending on the section of the webpage you are on.

After playing around with the code I cannot figure out how to do this. What do I need to do?

This is my code:

```js
$('#navbar li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,900,700,500);
html{
  font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
}
body{
  background:fixed
    url(images/bright_squares.png) #cccccc;
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#home {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-image:url(images/random_grey_variations.png);}
#about {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff;}
#portfolio {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff;}
#contact {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff;}

background-dark{
  background:fixed
    url(images/random_grey_variations.png); 
}

#navbar {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#navbar li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .2s;
}

#navbar li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: inherit;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0, background .2s;
}
#navbar li:hover:before {
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 50%;
  transition: all .1s, background .2s, margin-top .2s cubic-bezier(.5,30,.2,0);
}
#navbar li:hover,
#navbar li:hover:before {
  background: #3a3a3a;
}
#navbar li.active,
#navbar li.active:before {
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="navbar">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>

<div id="portfolio">
  <h1>portfolio</h1>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>

<div id="contact">
  <h1>contact</h1>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>

<div id="about">
  <h1>About Me</h1>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is exactly what you want to achieve? Keeping the arrow at the bottom of the blue section?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question. Just add this code inside the click function you already have.

```
$($(this).children().attr('href')).addClass('selected').siblings('div').removeClass('selected');
```

You will need to change the home link to #home instead of # though

Comment: Would this be the correct format <script>
 $('#navbar li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
 $($(this).children().attr('href')).addClass('selected').siblings('div').removeClass('selected');
});
</script>

Comment: Yes, that's it. It adds the class to the active div so you can use scrollspy or whatever you want to move to it.

Comment: If that works for you, please mark it as the answer. Thanks :p

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forgo all of that, here's the even quicker version.

```
<script>
    $('#navbar li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
        var x = $($(this).children().attr('href')).first().offset().top
        $('body').animate({
          scrollTop: x
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

This will add the scrolling animation I think you're looking for.